# Want to know how SQL Script works

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you please explain what the below script mean ?

It seems it delete 200,000 rows in specific table but how it can delete continually ?

If it deletes 200,000 rows and there are more rows to delete, it continues.

But I don't know how it works.

```
SET ROWCOUNT 200000;

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
  DELETE 
  FROM Table
  WHERE event_time<= '2013-12-31';

  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BREAK
END

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is deleting rows from the table in batches of 200,000, based on `ROWCOUNT`.  Note that use of this feature is not a good idea, because future versions may not support it.  The documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx).

Deleting rows from a table imposes a lot of overhead, in terms of locking and logging the transactions.  Breaking it into smaller pieces is often more efficient.

The variable `@@ROWCOUNT` is the number of rows actually deleted, so this is deleting until all rows are gone.